# How to disable automatic turning on of sound (El Capitan)

Tags: macos

Ever since I upgraded to El Capitan, my MBP does this annoying "helpful" turning on of my sound when I watch a video (Facebook or YouTube, at the very least) or have an incoming call/IM.

Each time I manually tap the sound-off button on my keyboard, but it doesn't "take" and recognize that when I turn off my volume manually, I really, truly do want it to stay off.

Any way to make my machine recognize that mute means mute-until-I-explicitly-unmute?

Comment: Does this happen if you explicitly set the volume to minimum rather than thwacking the mute key?

Comment: @MikeyT.K. I will try to see if that would work. What's strange is that OSX "respected" the mute key before; not it disables it when it (incorrectly) thinks I want audio enabled.

Comment: I do not seem to have this problem; if I mute, then visit Youtube in Safari, videos play with no sound. Using 10.11.